# Position absolute not working inside position fixed

Tags: html, css, position, styles

```
<div id="main" style="position: fixed">
   <div id="inner" style="position: absolute">
   </div>
</div>
```

Both `main` and `inner` containers taking `position: fixed`. How to make inner container with `position:absolute` and main container with `position:fixed` ?

Comment: would you post some demo?

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` properties when using `fixed`, `relative` or `absolute` positioning on an element.

```css
#main {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 10px;
}
#inner {
  background: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
   <div id="inner">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something similar ?

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="inner">
   </div>
</div>


#main {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
  border: 1px solid #000;

  top: 50px;
  left: 10px;
}

#inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #f00;

//  top: 0px;
//  left: 0px;

  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`position:absolute` will work according to it's parent `div`'s position property.
But `position:fixed` always will take it's position according to the user view port, no matter where the element resides. (No importance to it's parent element)

In the example *#main* is in `fixed` position. And have a `200px` `left` property assigned to it. So it will take a `200px` left to the viewport, where *#inner* also have a left:100px, but it will take a 100px left from the **parent** which is *#main*. If the inner has also a fixed position, it will take left from the viewport. (Un-comment the commented code in codepen to see it in action)

HTML

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="inner">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
  position: fixed;
  background: #cc3;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  left: 200px;
}
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #1d3;
  left: 100px;
  top:100px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/asim-coder/pen/LZNxJM

Comment: I have tried by adding `top` and `left` values. But not worked for me ! :(

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
    #main{ 
  background:#ccc; 
  width:300px;
  height:300px
}  
#inner{
   background:#fff; 
   text-align:center;
   margin:20px; 
   padding:20px
}

<div id="main" style="position: fixed">
   <div id="inner" style="position: absolute">
     inner div
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is jsfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/awvov63a/