# Is it possible to place bootstrap button and dropdown in different place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal, dropdown

```
 <div class="dropdown" style="position:fixed">
   <span class="icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>
</div>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="position:abosolute">
   <li id="1"></li>
   <li id="2"></li>
</ul>
```

I need to do something like this. That is icon in one div(fixed) and ul outside the div(absolute position) to make scrollable in page ? If I give within the same div both taking `fixed` position and dropdown becomes un-scrollable This is not working. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: can i ask you one thing? you have already asked this question in your last [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783835/position-absolute-not-working-inside-position-fixed) then why you are asking again, when you did not reply to any of answer in last question?

Comment: I didn't mention about dropdowns in my previous question. Thats why asked new one.

Comment: But the main moto is same..isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to get this working is by creating a Button linked with your Dropdown menu. Almost like in [this](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/) Bootstrap Example.

Comment: please provide proper code and not only link as they may be broken in future then your answer will be no use. Thank you